# aws cli elb / elbv2 - How to filter load balancers by DNSName?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-elb

I need to find out the arn of a load balancer. The only information I have is the DNS name.

It seems to be easy to extract the *region* from the DNS name, as it is part of it:

```
MyElbName.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Filtering, though, does not work:

```
# aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --filters "Name=DNSName,Values=MyElbName-1190680708.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws  help
  aws   help

Unknown options: --filters, Name=DNSName,Values=MyElbName-1190680708.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com --region "us-west-2"
#
```

Is the `--filters` option maybe just not available in the `elbv2` namespace? I have the same issue in the `elb` namespace, but in `elb`, even the *region* is not available.

Comment: Before trying to get the filtering to work, can you see the desired Load Balancer in the console? You will only be able to view Load Balancers that belong to your own AWS Account. Also, please note that there is no `--filter` option for this command. See: [describe-load-balancers — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. Yes, I can see the Load Balancer in the console, if I use `elbv2` and specify my region. - Thanks for the information about the lack of availability of that parameter; I did not find the information anywhere. I might need to filter by jq or so...

Answer (score 4):

There is no `--filters` option for `describe-load-balancers`. You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers | \
   jq '.LoadBalancers[] | 
       select(.DNSName == "your-dns-name.elb.amazonaws.com") | 
       .LoadBalancerArn'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query and jmespath

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancers[*].[LoadBalancerName,DNSName,LoadBalancerArn]' --output text
```